# Parallel development Pain in Java EE

Tags: java, configuration-management

Do you know any product like Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 that solves the parallel 
development pain/conflict for Java EE development?

Comment: Are there any particular requirements you'd like? I'd of thought standard scm tools would suffice otherwise :)

Comment: funny, I have never experienced the 'pain' you are talking about. Sometimes actually talking to your colleagues about what they do can be an old-fashioned but efficient solution. Apart from that: I would also suggest the (SVN | git) + maven + Hudson + JIRA approach

Answer (score 1):

subversion + jira + wiki ...

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Microsoft Team Foundation Server, but a combination of source control, continous integration (like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)) and a good issue tracker / collaboration tool (like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)) gives a good overview of current activities / quality over time / current issues / progress while allowing for collaboration through wikis and the issue tracker. Mailing lists and an IRC channel can be a good additions for more permanent and live discussions respectively.

In my opinion Trac is really nice since it is easy to use, has a 'team timeline' and shows great information - code diffs along with issue numbers and developer comments bundled together - giving a great 'togetherness' feeling in the team.

The continous integration solution can provide many different code and quality metrics over time without manual intervention. Great for management.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to pay for good products you can look at [Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) & [Youtrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) by Jetbrains. They provide useful tools for team programming.

If you work on an open source project, you can give a try to [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) & [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/).

And [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or [git](http://git-scm.com/) will be a good way to manage your sources.

(Teamcity is free for an open source projects too)

Answer (score 0):

[Saros - Distributed Collaborative Editing and Distributed Party Programming](http://www.saros-project.org/)

Pretty cool, just requires eclipse and a [xmpp server](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working in a team of 15 or so Java devs. I don't feel any pain of development. This is an environment using Maven, Subversion & Atlassian tools mainly. Maven makes it comparatively easy to build even large projects. Subversion does a decent job of updating & merging where necessary. Atlassian tools handle bug tracking, code review and automated builds but cost $$$. You could get by with Bugzilla and Hudson.

If by parallel you mean everyone gets their own branch then I suppose you could go with Clearcase but get ready to kiss your budget, sanity and productivity goodbye. Git might be a better choice for that kind of thing.